# How do I create a new files automatically depend on an existing variable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have many file in a folder, I would like to check the existing and matching of the file with variable that I initialize. Then, if the file exit and match, I want to get some information from the files (many file), then create a new file depend on how many file exist and match.

I tried this code, I can check the matching and existing file. I can create a new file and get the information from the file, but I only can create 1 file.
The information that I get from the file, each file is different.

```
$ID = "123"
$Pre = "ABC"
$Path = "C:\Folder"
$PO = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path
foreach ($File in $PO) {
    if (($File.Name -match $ID) -and ($File.Name -match $Pre)) {
        Write-Host ">>POfile Found: $File"
    } else {
        Write-Host ">>Check Again!"
    }
}

# CREATE FILE
$Jb_Path = "C:\Folder\Jb"
## GET INFORMATION
$count = 1
$Get_PO = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path\$File -File -Recurse
$POfile = Get-Random -InputObject $Get_PO -Count $count
Write-Host ">>Selected POfile= $POfile"
$FilteredContents = Get-Content $POfile | Where-Object {$_ -like "*;INFO*"}
$Get_INFO = $FilteredContents.Substring(5,2)
## NEW FILE
New-Item -Path $Jb_Path\NEW_$Pre$ID-$Get_INFO.txt -Force
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what about the code doesn't work the way you expected, or what you want to achieve in the first place. Please elaborate.

Comment: I already assigned a new quesetion here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/57067553/11099245

Answer (score 0):

- In the section `# CREATE FILE` you are referencing the variable `$File` which has the last value iterated in the previous foreach (even if it didn't match the if condition).
- Asuming the `$Pre` is for prefix and comes first in a file name simply do a

  ```
  Get-ChildItem "$Path\*$Pre*$ID*"
  ```

  to only get file names for your criteria.
- As $File contains only one file name a Get-Random doesn't make sense, especially as it might not contain a line with `;INFO`

---

Assuming the two characters to extract are in front of `;INFO` this untested script might do:

```
$Pre    = "ABC"
$ID     = "123"
$Path   = "C:\Folder"
$Jb_Path= "C:\Folder\Jb"

Get-ChildItem "$Path\*$Pre*$ID*" | Get-Content | 
  Select-String -Pattern '^.....(..).*;INFO' | 
    Get-Random | ForEach-Object {
      $NewFile = Join-Path $Jb_Path ('NEW_{0}{1}-{2}.txt' -f $Pre,
        $ID,$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value)
      New-Item -Path $NewFile -ItemType File -Force -WhatIf
    }
```

It will only output what it would do without the `-WhatIf` parameter.
If no file matching the criteria and RegEx pattern is found it will silently continue.

If my assumptions led me wrong, enhance your question be editing it with more details.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I assigned a new question for more detail.